# Splitting a div into two, for multiple sign up forms

Tags: css, html

Im trying to put in two sign up forms on a single page, but to effectively do this id like to split the center div into two seperate columns to achieve this.

Ive poasted the code below:

```
<div id="content">
        <!-- Left Content Start -->
        <div class="instruct" id="instruct-div">
              <div class="contentcol">
                    <!-- starts content-->
                <h1>Continue...</h1>
                <div id="password">
                  <p>All required fields must be completed. Required fields are denoted by (*)</p></div>
              </div>
        </div>
```

Can anyone advise the best way to achieve this without ruining the rest of the site layout?

Ill try to provide any exxtra information people want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly, but if you've a div and want to columns of content in this div, I think you should make two div's inside the containing div. The left div needs width: 50% and float:left, then the right div should float up nicely next to the left div.

Did that make any sense?

Comment: That does make sense and i think by doing what you have said ive managed to do what I wanted.

My main problem was that my stylesheet uses the same id's throughout the pages and this particular page required alot of new/different css commands.

Ive added a few overwriting css styles within the div and its working great now thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a ***2 column layout in CSS***

Here's a nice guide to create one

[Simple 2 column CSS layout](http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/developing_with_web_standards/csslayout/2-col/)